# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'MyEntity' on 'Castle.Proxies.SalonProxy'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**Hi everyone,** I have Asp.Net Core Web API project that is using Entity Framework Core 6.0 and Postgresql as a database

I configured my entities and their relation. Everything is fine, but there is only problem in Generic Repository Design Pattern

If I use just `context.Products.ToList()`, it is working perfect. But whenever I am using it with Generic Repository Design Pattern. I got an error. But there is an interesting thing. Whenever I use break point just 10 seconds or even more and I keep it up after 10 seconds, there is no error. Everything is working perfect. Is there Asynchronous problem, I never used it ?

**Error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQCRJ.png)

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from
> 'Seats' on 'Castle.Proxies.SalonProxy'.
>
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An error was generated for warning
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning':
> An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation 'Seats.SalonProxy' after
> the associated DbContext was disposed. This exception can be
> suppressed or logged by passing event ID
> 'CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning' to the
> 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
> 'AddDbContext'.

```
public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IEntityRepository<TEntity>
where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        using (TContext context = new TContext())
        {
            var addedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
            addedEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return addedEntity.Entity;
        }
    }

    

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        using (TContext context = new TContext())
        {
            var deletedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
            deletedEntity.State = EntityState.Deleted;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        using (TContext context = new TContext())
        {
            var result = context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(filter);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public List<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        using (TContext context = new TContext())
        {
    
         var result = filter == null
          ? context.Set<TEntity>().ToList()
          : context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).ToList();
          return result;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**My Salon Entity**

```
public class Salon : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string SalonNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Seat> Seats { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

**My Seat Entity**

```
    public class Seat : IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    
        public int SeatNumber { get; set; }
    
        public int SalonId { get; set; }
        public virtual Salon Salon { get; set; }
    }
```

**MyDbContext**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies().ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Ignore(CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning))
            .UseNpgsql("Server=localhost;Database=BiletsgoDB;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=123456");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>().HasOne(t => t.Category).WithMany(b => b.Tickets).HasForeignKey(t => t.CategoryId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>().HasOne(t => t.Salon).WithMany(b => b.Tickets).HasForeignKey(t => t.SalonId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Seat>().HasOne(t => t.Salon).WithMany(b => b.Seats).HasForeignKey(t => t.SalonId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<TicketFile>().HasOne(t => t.Ticket).WithMany(b => b.TicketFiles).HasForeignKey(t => t.TicketId);
        }

        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TicketFile> TicketFiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Seat> Seats { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Salon> Salons { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The error indicates you are accessing the `Seats` property after you have returned from the `Get` or the `GetAll` methods but that property was not materialized before returning from the method (and disposing of your db context).  This is one of many reasons lazy evaluation is best avoided and eager loading (via `.Include`) preferred.

Comment: @KirkWoll Thank you so much, I understood better now. Do you have a suggestion ? How do I use `Include` method with Generic Repository Design Pattern? Because I might have many entities.

Comment: Well, my own opinion is that the generic repository pattern isn't providing much value over just using the `DbContext` directly in your code.  (And using an in-memory db for unit testing if that's the reason you're using the pattern at all)  Or make your repositories more narrowly focused and only return domain entities that will always be fully populated.  (for example, a separate repository method to get the `Seats` for a given `Salon` and not including the seats in the `Salon` type you return at all)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I solved, You're right, probably it is not an efficient way. I'm going to implement your suggestion. Likewise, I will add my solution as an answer. @KirkWoll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Solved the problem**

params includes our entity relations

```
 public List<TEntity> GetAll(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] including)
    {
        using (TContext context = new TContext())
        {

            var include = context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
            including.ToList().ForEach(item =>
            {
                include = include.Include(item);
            });
            return include.ToList();
        }
    }
```

And I run this method from my business layer

```
_salonDal.GetAll(t => t.Seats,t => t.Tickets)
```

But I realized this way it is not efficient. Generic Repository base should use fundamentals entities. That's my opinion

Comment: It's not clear if you're answering your question here or just adding new information. If the latter, that should be done by editing the question.

Comment: @GertArnold I solved. I am not adding new information. This is a solution

Comment: choice your answer as an acceptable answer after 48 hours, thanks.

Comment: Instead of introducing List allocation and closure object, just use old plain `foreach`